# Unable to import the TextDataset class from the aitextgen library

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to build a machine learning model that generates job descriptions by finetuning the gpt-neo model with my dataset of job descriptions

I tried importing TextDataset class from aitextgen and I keep facing this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DeepSpeedPlugin' from 'pytorch_lightning.plugins
```

i have literally tried lots of suggestions from chat gpt which involved installing the DeepSpeedPluging separately, downgrading my aitextgen library upgrading my pytorch library
uninstalling and reinstalling pytorch and aitextgen  but none of the suggested methods worked
here is my code snippet

```
!pip install aitextgen
import aitextgen.TokenDataset
```

and at this level i get the error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-24eff681443c> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import aitextgen.TokenDataset

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/aitextgen/aitextgen.py in <module>
     12 import torch
     13 from pkg_resources import resource_filename
---> 14 from pytorch_lightning.plugins import DeepSpeedPlugin
     15 from tqdm.auto import trange
     16 from transformers import (

ImportError: cannot import name 'DeepSpeedPlugin' from 'pytorch_lightning.plugins' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/__init__.py)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the versioning of pytorch-lightning, transformers, and aitextgen.

Like this:

```
!pip install -qq pytorch-lightning==1.7.0 transformers==4.21.3 aitextgen==0.6.0
```

There is an issue opened addressing this: https://github.com/minimaxir/aitextgen/issues/215